# printing float precision precision in numpy jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, precision

I want to print floats with precision 4.
I use numpy , jupyter notebook
I tried:

```
%precision %.4g
%precision 2
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
print(0.6776776)
```

the output:

```
0.6776776
```

Any Ideas what is wrong ?

```
# Name                    Version                   
ipython                   6.4.0                    
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            
msgpack-python            0.5.6            
python                    3.6.5                
python-dateutil           2.7.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Print does not care about numpy or IPython formatters. It calls str() in the Background, any formatting has to be done using Standard print formatters (%.2f and the like).
Look at the different Output for:

```
%precision 3
a = 0.6776776
print(a)
a
```

The result will be:

```
0.6776776
0.678
```